# CSRF issue reported at read-only class variable

Tags: c#, .net, csrf

We found below logs in CICD pipeline

CWE-352: Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF): agent-pipeline/src/feature/product/productcontroller.cs:34

```
namespace SampleProject.Feature.Product.Controllers
{
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public class ProductController : BaseController
{
private readonly ProductContext _productContext = new ProductContext(); \\issue reported here
...
```

Issue is reported at above given line. What else can be done to fix this issue?

Comment: I think this will be a false positive by your sast tool.

Comment: @GaborLengyel
Did you mean we should go for mitigation steps then `https://help.veracode.com/r/improve_mitigation?section=mitigate__propose`